# Users are not installed from Appexchange package

Tags: appexchange

I have created package in my Org.

I installed application package in other Org, All components came including Vf page etc.But i couldnt see users that are there in my previous Org to reflect in my installed Org.

Can we make users also install when installing in package.
If yes, What I need to do.

Thanks
Arun K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot package users into a package. You can package profiles, in which case the profiles would be installed, but users must be re-created in each new organization. This is especially true because user names must be unique, so it would be impossible to simply re-use the same user login. However, if you use an InstallHandler script, you could attempt to create those users through programmatic code. You would need to make sure the script modifies the user name so it is unique.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.I added profile and made package and I installed that package in other Org.But couldnt see Custom profile in installed package.Not sure why that happened